# Customize xslt listview webpart from xsl

Tags: xslt

I was asked to show top 3 fields of a custom list in sharepoint through xsltlistview webpart. From the help of the blog:http://maulikdhorajia.blogspot.dk/2011/06/sharepoint-2010-xsltlistviewwebpart.html i kind of created the xsl but i have to create headers at the top of each listitem and the background color of the header needs to be taken from the custom list's column: ColorCode.
Please anyone help me as i dont know anything about Xslt. how to do dat??

Thanx in advance

my xsl is as follow:

```
  <td width="33%" valign="top" style="background-color: #F8F6F7">
      <div id="linkitem" class="item">
        <div>


          <a style="font-size: 14pt;font-weight: normal;color: #333333;**background-color:{$color};>**
          <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>
          </a>
        </div>
        <img style="height:100px; background-color: #F8F6F7">
          <xsl:attribute name="src">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Picture"></xsl:value-of>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="alt">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Title"></xsl:value-of>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </img>
        <div>
          <a style="font-size: 14pt;font-weight: normal;color: #333333">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Name" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div style="font-size: 8pt;color: #999999;margin-bottom:5px">
          <xsl:value-of select="@Email" />
        </div>
        <div style="font-size: 10pt;color: #333333">
          <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="@Address" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>

</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="$CurPos = 2">
  <td width="33%" valign="top" style="background-color: #F8F6F7">
    <div id="linkitem" class="item">
      <img style="height:100px; background-color: #F8F6F7">
        <xsl:attribute name="src">
          <xsl:value-of select="@Picture"></xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="alt">
          <xsl:value-of select="@Title"></xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </img>
      <div>
        <a style="font-size: 14pt;font-weight: normal;color: #333333">
          <xsl:value-of select="@Name" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div style="font-size: 8pt;color: #999999;margin-bottom:5px">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Email" />
      </div>
      <div style="font-size: 10pt;color: #333333">
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="@Address" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="$CurPos = 3">
  <td width="33%" valign="top" style="background-color: #F8F6F7">
    <div id="linkitem" class="item">
      <img style="height:100px; background-color: #F8F6F7">
        <xsl:attribute name="src">
          <xsl:value-of select="@Picture"></xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="alt">
          <xsl:value-of select="@Title"></xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </img>
      <div>
        <a style="font-size: 14pt;font-weight: normal;color: #333333">
          <xsl:value-of select="@Name" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div style="font-size: 8pt;color: #999999;margin-bottom:5px">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Email" />
      </div>
      <div style="font-size: 10pt;color: #333333">
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="@Address" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the colour column is included in the columns in your view.

You can then use it in the XSL.  eg:

```
<td width="33%" valign="top" style="background-color: {@ColourCode}">
```

The curly brackets around the item is a shortcut for:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@ColourCode" />
```

Another option is to create the attribute separately:

```
<td width="33%" valign="top">
 <xsl:attribute name="style">
  background-color: <xsl:value-of select="@ColourCode" />
 </xsl:attribute>
 etc
```